# Minor gc two times per second,it is all right?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

This is my jvm config:
[image]

This is the statistic of gc: jstat -gcutil -t 14148 1000 300
[image]

It's the config is ok? I think the minor gc is too much.

Comment: Depends on what you're doing... My personal opinion, 2 GCs per second is excessive. But how are we supposed to know without even looking at code? Do you even have a problem?

Comment: I cache vast deal and poi in local cache,because Christmas Day，the qps suddenly growth.

Comment: How are we supposed to know that config is good if we don't know what your program even is? This question makes 0 sense. We cannot read your mind..

Comment: I think from the statistic can read something,if somebody is experienced...

Comment: Minor gc happens to clear young generation  objects located in Eden space.  Check how frequently Eden space is filled up and how much free heap is available in that area.  Check any explicit gc calls by your application to free up heap memory.  Minor gc shouldn't have much side affects on your performance.  Even it happens in our application servers,  major gc is the evil most of the times.

Comment: Implying I'm not experienced? I've been profiling applications for the past year or so. 2 GCs a second tells us your application is creating a lot of short-lived objects. Is that a good or bad thing? How are we supposed to know if we don't know what your application is?? You have lost my help. Voting to close for "Unclear what you are asking", as you refuse to ask a question we would be able to answer. Improve your question and maybe someone else may be able to help. Keep in mind, VM arguments depend on the type of application...

Comment: Nothing can be deduced from those statistics.  We can't tell you if something is wrong, or suggest what the (hypothetical) cause might be.

Comment: @Vince Emigh You said right,my application created lots of short-lived objects.I read the code again,and found that there is a big data in cache,and every request come, it copy parts of the "big data" in the cache. So cause a lot of short-live object create,thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

> It's the config is ok?

Do you have a justification for each parameter? If not then strip them away and start with the JVM defaults and only add parameters when you understand what they do and why you need them.

> I think the minor gc is too much.

On what grounds? Does it affect your application latencies? Your CPU load? Have you measured pause times?

Ideally GCs should be unobstrusive and self-tuning, you should only concerned yourself with them if you notice any performance issues with the application itself